# im trying use bisection method to find the root of the function x^4 - 5x^3 + (22/3)x^2 - (116/27)x + (8/9) in [0,1] with e = 0.01

Tags: python, python-3.x, bisection

here's the code i made

```
def bisection(f, a, b, e):
    step = 1
    condition = True
    while condition:
        c = (a+b)/2
        if f(a) * f(c) < 0:
            b = c
        else:
            a = c
        if f(c) == 0:
            break
        step = step + 1
        condition = abs(f(a)-f(b)) > e
        print(c)
    return(c)
    if f(a)* f(b) > 0:
        print("no roots")
    else:
        bisection(f, a, b, e)

    a, b, e = input().split(' ')
    a = float(a)
    b = float(b)
    print(round(root, 4))
```

but I'm getting a root of c = 0.171875
instead of 0.6875

Comment: With `def f(x): return x**4 - 5*x**3 + (22/3)*x**2 - (116/27)*x + (8/9)` and `bisection(f, 0, 1, 0.00001)` I get `0.671875`. So your bisection code works, but you probably made a typo in the function.

Comment: thanks, you're right - I entered my f(x) with a typo